# Is it possible to automatically delete a user profile while logging off?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

We have a computer for public use. I want to delete the user profile every time the user logs out to make sure that no potential private information of a user is stored on the machine!

Is it possible to automatically delete a user profile while logging off? (Windows 7 OS)

Comment: Is it running on a network? Are you using Group Policy? If so, that's the best way to go. Otherwise there are options to run scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the Windows built-in guest account. You can activate it like so:

1. Open the start menu, and click on your user image at the top to the right
2. Click the link `manage another account`
3. You should see the guest account in the list. Click on it.
4. Click the **enable** button.

The guest account should now appear in the welcome screen. It has very little privileges, but data will not be stored. See [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Turn-the-guest-account-on-or-off) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but not effective solution. Our users need to load their own profiles because we have public area computers and then delete them on exit.  Nothing to do with privacy and everything to do with speed.  After 20 users have logged in....well you can imagine.  Takes 10 minutes for the PC to boot.  I don't think Windows 7 can do it (which is ridiculous).  I believe programs like [deep freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/) can do this.  Still annoyed I need to buy a program for something so obvious.